# Vue.js - Material Design Lite components not upgraded automatically unless refreshed

Tags: html, css, vue.js, material-design, vuejs2

I'm using *Material Design Lite* components in my *Vue.js* project. when I redirect on another page my UI appears to be broken and looks like this:

[image]

but when I refresh it, it is somewhat *fixed* and it looks like it what supposed to be:

[image]

I checked the console and found something strange in the *elements* section. the line of code (highlighted by blue) looks like this BEFORE refreshing

[image]

.. and becomes like this AFTER refreshing:

[image]

it seems that when I refresh the page, the components are *upgraded*. But it is not automatically upgraded the moment I click the link and redirects to that page. How do I fix this issue? I don't wanna press F5 everytime I go to a new page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding this to your created hook:

```
created() {
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    componentHandler.upgradeDom();
    componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();
  });
}
```

I had to use this to fix the animation of some MDL's components.

Comment: I thought it can be put in main.js or root component, but it needs to be put in **every component's created life hook** for it to work. thanks btw

Comment: Good to know, I remember how I scratched my head so hard to figure out why MDL's text input component didn't work, so I'm glad i could help. BTW, Google seemed to give up MDL and created something new now: https://material.io/

Comment: Thanks!

At first I have to use `window.componentHandler` for accessing it.

I've tried `beforeMount() { this.$nextTick(() => { window.componentHandler.upgradeElement(this.$el); }); }` but with no effect.

Now I put this into App.vue in it works for all of my views:
`
  watch: {
    $route(to, from) {
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        window.componentHandler.upgradeDom();
        window.componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();
      });
    }
  }
`

Answer (score 0):

In order to take advantage of VueJS as a single page app or refresh less function you need to add a method that will update the data object that is being displayed in the v-for loop.

Add another function under `methods` that gets the updated data and then on the promise calls another function to set the updated data.

e.g.

```
  methods: {
    getUpdatedData: function (data) {
     //
    },
    setUpdatedData: function (data) {
     //
    },
  }
```

And then to have getUpdatedData(data) triggered by your events or directly inlie with a `v-on`

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Method-Event-Handlers

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html